# How to properly unit test code that calculates dates and times

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

## tl;dr

I have some production code and a test class. I want to validate the behavior of the production code but the test just feels like it's repeating the production code and therefore just testing .NET itself.

### Production Code

This represents the concept of a `Maintenance` which can use its `LastMaintenance` date to calculate it's `NextMaintenance` date based on the `MaintenanceScale`.

```
public enum MaintenanceScale
{
    None,
    Minute,
    Hour,
    Day,
    Week,
    Month,
    Year
}

public class Maintenance
{
    public int Span { get; set; }
    public MaintenanceScale Scale { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LastMaintenance { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? NextMaintenance { get; set; }
    public void CalulateNextMaintenance()
    {
        if (LastMaintenance == null)
        {
            NextMaintenance = null;
            return;
        }

        switch (Scale)
        {
            case MaintenanceScale.Minute:
                NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddMinutes(Span);
                break;
            case MaintenanceScale.Hour:
                NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddHours(Span);
                break;
            case MaintenanceScale.Day:
                NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddDays(Span);
                break;
            case MaintenanceScale.Week:
                NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddDays(Span * 7);
                break;
            case MaintenanceScale.Month:
                NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddMonths(Span);
                break;
            case MaintenanceScale.Year:
                NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddYears(Span);
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }
}
```

### Test Code (NUnit)

This uses [nunit](/questions/tagged/nunit) to test the code works against all the possible maintenance scales.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MaintenanceTypeTests
{
    const int Span = 42;
    static DateTimeOffset _now = DateTimeOffset.Now;

    static Maintenance NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale scale, DateTimeOffset? lastMaintenance) =>
        new Maintenance
        {
            Scale = scale,
            Span = Span,
            LastMaintenance = lastMaintenance
        };

    static TestCaseData[] _recalculationData =
    {
        new TestCaseData(NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale.Week, null))
        {
            ExpectedResult = null,
            TestName = "No Last Maintenance"
        },
        new TestCaseData(NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale.Minute, _now))
        {
            ExpectedResult = _now.AddMinutes(Span),
            TestName = MaintenanceScale.Minute.ToString()
        },
        new TestCaseData(NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale.Hour, _now))
        {
            ExpectedResult = _now.AddHours(Span),
            TestName = MaintenanceScale.Hour.ToString()
        },
        new TestCaseData(NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale.Day, _now))
        {
            ExpectedResult = _now.AddDays(Span),
            TestName = MaintenanceScale.Day.ToString()
        },
        new TestCaseData(NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale.Week, _now))
        {
            ExpectedResult = _now.AddDays(Span * 7),
            TestName = MaintenanceScale.Week.ToString()
        },
        new TestCaseData(NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale.Month, _now))
        {
            ExpectedResult = _now.AddMonths(Span),
            TestName = MaintenanceScale.Month.ToString()
        },
        new TestCaseData(NewMaintenance(MaintenanceScale.Year, _now))
        {
            ExpectedResult = _now.AddYears(Span),
            TestName = MaintenanceScale.Year.ToString()
        }
    };

    [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(_recalculationData))]
    public DateTimeOffset? CanCalulateNextMaintenance(Maintenance maintenance)
    {
        maintenance.CalulateNextMaintenance();
        return maintenance.NextMaintenance;
    }
}
```

### The Question

To me it seems both the production code and the test are calling the same methods and therefore the test is only validating the .NET datetime methods.

**Is it ok to use the same code that calculates the result in both production and the unit test OR should your unit test have hard-coded inputs with known outputs?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your test has some, but not much, value**

It'll tell you if someone modifies the code's logic (and doesn't update the unit test). So that is something.

**What I would do**

I would hardcode the inputs and the expected outputs instead of calculating them with c#.

Then I would pick date/times that fall on interesting edge cases. For example, what happens when the date/time falls just before daylight savings time comes into effect and the expected output is on the other side?

Also, if your system requires it, consider coaxing the tests to run in different timezone contexts, e.g. time zones that are or are not UTC, or timezones that either have or don't have DST.

Answer (score 3):

This test checks if `Maintenance.CalulateNextMaintenance()` assigns correct date to  `NextMaintenance`.

Imagine a scenario:
Developer made a mistake in production code, let's say he changed the method so it looks like this:

```
public void CalulateNextMaintenance()
{
    if (LastMaintenance == null)
    {
        NextMaintenance = null;
        return;
    }

    switch (Scale)
    {
        case MaintenanceScale.Minute:
            NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddHours(Span);
            break;
        case MaintenanceScale.Hour:
            NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddHours(Span * 2);
            break;
        case MaintenanceScale.Day:
            NextMaintenance = LastMaintenance.Value.AddDays(Span);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

As you see, he accidentaly removed a few cases and didn't notice he modified some parameters.
The test will catch errors:

1. For `MaintenanceScale.Minute` method assigns wrong value
2. For `MaintenanceScale.Hour` method assigns wrong value
3. For `Week`, `Month` and `Year` (which are correct) method throws exception.

Note, that in TDD (Test Driven Development) usually the test is written **before** the production code. There is nothing wrong with it.